# SELECT ROW FROM SQL/MYSQL BASED ON GROUP BY OR ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a value from sql based on the max on a column

```
 A                 b               c
|         1 |       1 |            4.5 |
|         1 |       2 |            7.5 |
|         1 |       3 |            8.5 |
|         2 |       1 |              1 |
|         2 |       2 |             11 |
|         2 |       3 |              9 |
|         3 |       1 |             12 |
|         3 |       2 |              8 |
|         3 |       3 |             10 |
|         4 |       1 |             13 |
|         4 |       2 |             15 |
|         4 |       3 |             10 |
```

I am trying to retrieve

```
4 | 15
3 | 12
2 | 11
```

but i keep getting

```
|                 8.5 |
|                  11 |
|                  12 |
```

I am running this sql queries and i just need tips in completing it

```
select max(c) from risk_score group by a limit 3;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you adding the limit 3?

Comment: Please only tag the relevant RDBMS.

Comment: Based on the title, I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like:

```
select a, max(c)
from risk_score
group by a
order by 2 desc
fetch first 3 rows only
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you mind if i ask a follow up question @connor McDonald?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `limit 3` in your query you are fetching the top 3 entries.

But as per your output you need to fetch last 3 results.

```
select a, MAX(c) from risk_score group by A ORDER BY A DESC limit 3;
```